# Bootstrap 3 fixed width layout, full width footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with a fixed width.

My footer exist of two colums (left & right) with each a different background color.
I want the content of my footer to be wrapped in the '.container' so it aligns with the rest of the content on my website.

**Now here is the thing I can't get to work:**

I want to make it look like the footer has a full width. So left of the '.container' should be one color and the right an other.

Plus when the resolution gets below a certain point the two colums should shift under each other but with the background colors still fullwidth.

**See picuture to make it all more clear.**
[picture](http://www.eenwaarheid.nl/wordpress/wp-content/themes/heyman/img/img.png)

My first thought was using a background image on '.container-wrapper' and then on the mobile version a different background aligned from the middle. Like this:

CSS

```
.kleur {
background:url(img/test-bg.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
background-position:center; }


@media (max-width: 992px) {
.kleur {
    background:url(img/test-bg2.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:center; }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="fullwidthcontainer kleur">
<div class="kleur-links" style="background:#cfcfcf; height:100%; width:100%"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8" style="background:#feff8b;">  <br/><br/><br/> <br/><br/><br/>  </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background:#8bd7ff;">  <br/><br/><br/> <br/><br/><br/> </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

[Link to working example, scroll down](http://www.eenwaarheid.nl/wordpress/)

This works fine for Desktop, but for Mobile it only works if the two columns have exactly the same height. I really like the height to be variable, but don't have any idea how...

Anyone any thought?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fluid solution:

[Fluid solution without backgrounds](http://www.eenwaarheid.nl/fluid/)

But I rather have a solution with a fixed width